# Let $(A,+,*)$ be a ring with $9$ elements. Show that the following statements are equivalent

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $(A,+,* )$ be a ring with $9$ elements. Show that the following statements are equivalent

1. For every $x \in A\setminus\{0\}$ there exists $a \in \{-1,0,1\}$ and $b\in\{-1,1\}$ such that $x^2+ax+b=0$
2. $(A,+,* )$ is a field

I just started taking algebra and I don't really know how to deal with this problem. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: What is your definition of "ring"? Are you assuming that multiplication is commutative? That $1\in A$?

Comment: Why not use $\times$ rather than $*$ for multiplication? We're doing maths here not programming!

Comment: For the implication 1 --> 2, you are searching for every X an Y such that the equation XY=1 holds. You indeed have an equation by hp: can you see how to conclude?

Comment: @RobArthan It is an arbitrary ring operation; one can use whatever symbol they like ($\ast$, $\cdot$, $\times$, $\bullet$, $\circlearrowleft$, whatever).  I'm not sure how changing the notation would make the question any better (or worse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming $A$ to be commutative and $1\in A$.

$1 \implies 2$ : $\forall x\neq 0$, $$x^2 +ax + b= 0 \iff x(x+a) = -b$$ Since $b = \pm 1$, either $x+a$ or $-(x+a)$ is the inverse of $x$. Thus $A$ is a field.

$2 \implies 1$ : Assume there exists $x$ s.t. for all $(a,b) \in \{-1,0,1\}\times \{-1,1\}$, $x^2+ax+b \neq 0$. Then $x \notin \{-1, 0, 1\}$ and thus $x^{-1} \notin \{-1, 0, 1\}$.

But since $x^2+ax = x(x+a) \neq \pm 1$ for all $a\in \{-1,0,1\}$,  we have $x^{-1} \notin \left \{ \pm(x-1), \pm x, \pm (x+1) \right \}$.

Because $x\notin \{-1,0,1\}$, this last set has cardinal $6$ and doesn't intersect $\{-1,0,1\}$. But this leaves no more possibility for $x^{-1}$, because $A$ has cardinal $9$ : thus $A$ is not a field, a contradiction.

Comment: @krirkkrirk I'm sorry but I've been trying for a long time to understand the last part but I just cannot. Can you tell me why there is no more possibility for $x^-1$ ?

Comment: The set $\left \{ \pm(x-1), \pm x, \pm (x+1) \right \}$ has cardinal $6$, the set $\{ -1, 0, 1\}$ has cardinal $3$, and they share no element. This means their union has cardinal $9$. But their union is a subset of $A$, which has cardinal $9$. So this union *is* $A$.

Comment: Now $x^{-1}$ doesn't belong to this union, so it doesn't belong to $A$ - that is it doesn't exist.... which is a contradiction since we assumed $A$ to be a field.

Comment: Oh, now I understand it.Thank you very much!!!.